# Xcode 4.2 (build 4D199) + Python: Console output is different to the expected (e.g. no UTF-8 characters)

Tags: python, xcode, utf-8, xcode4.2

I am using Python 3.2.2 in Xcode 4.2 (build 4D199) on Mac OS X 10.7.2 and as follows:

**main.py**

```
#coding=utf-8
print("ľťď", 1+1)
print("ľťď")
```

**Output in the console (Shift+Cmd+C):**

```
('\xc4\xbe\xc5\xa5\xc4\x8f', 2)
ľťď
```

**Expected output (e.g. IDLE works well):**

```
ľťď 2
ľťď
```

Now given the fact that it also includes the brackets, apostrophes and comma, I presume that this behaviour is a result of the console's debugging nature, hence the real question is probably how to make the console to show the final output. The behaviour however seems a bit inconsistent and since this is my first encounter with Xcode and Python, my question is rather broad.

**TL;DR:** Is it possible to make the Xcode's console to output the same as e.g. IDLE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now given the fact that it also includes the brackets, apostrophes and comma, I presume that this behaviour is a result of the console's debugging nature

It's not. This is the difference between Python 2 and 3.

```
$ python2
>>> print("ľťď", 1+1)
('\xc4\xbe\xc5\xa5\xc4\x8f', 2)

$ python3
>>> print("ľťď", 1+1)
ľťď 2
```

You're actually running two different Python versions. Since Python 3 is not backwards compatible, you should pick either 2 or 3 for your project and stick with it.

Comment: D'oh! I am sorry, I have forgotten to change the project to use the new python3 instead of the python2 included with the system. I suspected the answer would be very simple, but not as this. Sorry for my beginner's negligence and thank you for saving me.

Comment: I am not sure whether this is for another question or just a second silly mistake of mine, but after changing the interpreter, I get a UnicodeEncodeError, which is again only in Xcode—IDLE works fine. It says: `UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character '\u013e' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`. ASCII works fine in Xcode as well.

Comment: @HarroldCavendish: that's a new question. Not enough context to answer this one.

Comment: Okay, I am going to post it. Thank you.